# Query for all rows with created_at between certain hours?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to retrieve all rows from a table where the created_at timestamp is during a certain hour ... say 04:00 and 05:00.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
RecordNameHere.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM `table_name_here` WHERE HOUR(created_at) = HOUR('4:01:00')")
```

The MySQL documentation is awesome: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Comment: @james A tricky way?  Tricky code doesn't impress, only annoys.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple hour range (eg: records between in 4:00 to 6:00)

```
User.all(:conditions => "HOUR(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", 4, 5)
```

For single hour use the following syntax:

```
User.all(:conditions => "HOUR(created_at) = ?", 4)
```

**Note 1**
The `HOUR` method returns the hour in 24 hour format. Provide the hour value accordingly.

Comment: Won't this grab all users who were created between `4:00:00` and `5:59:99`?

Comment: Yes, for a single hour range user should use `=` operator rather than BETWEEN. I have updated my answer to reflect that.